# Read words in unknown amount of arguments discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
async def add(ctx, *, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
    for i in list(msg):
      print(i)
```

When I run the command[image]

It runs it back but in console I get [image]
And I want it to print the words on the same line so like

```
hello!
im
happy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying

```
for i in list(msg):
     print(i)
```

you tell the code to run through every letter seperately. To run through each word use

```
for word in msg.split(" "):
     print(word)
```